# how to pass two parameter in route controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

i want pass two parameter `id` and `page` to action. but when i use this code

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("Actor/{id:int}/{page:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Actor(int id, int page, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    var data = await _videoService.GetActorVideos(id, page, cancellationToken);
    return View(data);
}
```

Routing error occurs when program is start. It never reaches the `_videoService` line and the `Actor` action is not executed.

and shows me this error

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: That's not the code where that error happens.

Comment: @SᴇM If it worked correctly I wouldn't ask questions

Comment: Post `GetActorVideos` code.

Comment: @FarhadZamani Remove the call to `_videService.GetActorVideos(...) ` and confirm that `id` and `page` are not set to the values you expect. If that is the case, please update your question with "how" you are calling the API. As mentioned in the other comment, the error you've posted is not raised by the code you have posted. It is potentially raised by the `_videoService` call but we need to remove the call to prove that.

Comment: @SimplyGed Routing error occurs when program is start. It never reaches the `_videoService` line and the`Actor` action is not executed

Comment: @FarhadZamani As stated earlier the error is not in the code you had posted. You need to a debugger to step through your code determine where the error is occurring (possibly in `startup.cs`). Then add that code to your question. As it stands we are unable to see where the error is happening and provide a solution.

Comment: @SimplyGed thank you for explanation :). I fixed the problem this way `[Route("Actor/{id:int}")]` then I called actor action that way `/Actor/4?page=1`

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet works for me. I slightly modified it and put a breakpoint on the line that starts with "var data". If I navigate to an URL that resolves to this route via a browser all parameters have a value.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Actor/{id:int}/{page:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Actor(int id, int page, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    var data = (id, page, cancellationToken);
    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters by query.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("Actor/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Actor(int id, int page = 1, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var data = await _videoService.GetActorVideos(id, page, cancellationToken);  
    return View(data);
}
```

Use Query String for Page
In this way.